# Virtualenv error: command 'cmake' failed: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, virtualenv

I get the following error in my virtualenv when installing; `snowflake-connector-python`

```
% pip3 install snowflake-connector-python

Collecting snowflake-connector-python
  Downloading snowflake-connector-python-2.9.0.tar.gz (394 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 394.3/394.3 kB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  ...

  Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow
       Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml): started
       Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
       error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  ...

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my_virtualenvs/tester/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
       from cmake import cmake
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
       error: command '/my_virtualenvs/tester/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
```

cmake is installed in the directory noted in the error and is available via the PATH:

```
% ECHO $PATH
/my_virtualenvs/tester/bin/cmake:/my_virtualenvs/tester/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I can import cmake in the Python shell and call it via the terminal:

```
% bin/cmake --version
cmake version 3.25.0
```

Environment:

- MacOS 12.5 Monterey
- Apple Silicon M1

How can I solve this error?

Comment: What Python version are you using? We don't support yet Python 3.11 if that's what you're using.

Comment: That was totally the cause of the problem. When I pointed the virtualenv to Python 3.9 the issue was resolved. Thank you @Sergiu !